# Auto Resizing Image

Tags: lightbox2

Lightbox2 is auto resizing the image in my lightbox to a maximum of 274 pixels wide and is stretching the height. I set the option to 1500 pixels wide with the options method but it does not fix this. I want the full image to show in the lightbox not some smaller and stretched version. Anyone know a fix or if this plug in is just broken?

Answer (score 0):

To make your images expand to their full resolution, you will have to modify two files. Go to `../lightbox/js`

Open `lightbox.js` and change

```
fitImagesInViewport: true,
```

to

```
fitImagesInViewport: false,
```

and save.

Then open `lightbox.min.js` and change

```
fitImagesInViewport: !0,
```

to

```
fitImagesInViewport: !1,
```

and save.

All images will show on full res instead of being downsampled to the viewscreen size.

I asked Lokesh to add a option that will show a little magnifier when the image has been downsampled so that the reader will see the full res image when clicking on it, but I'm not sure he will/can implement this, nor when.